# How to Limit a textbox for type url in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a `TextBox` and `Button`.
I want it when the user types in `TextBox`, for example, "*stackoverflow*", a `MessageBox`  will show saying:

> Please complete the URL - and if the user type's "stackoverflow.com"

The program then continues and takes them onto that website. However, if the URL does not contain an extension such as (.co.uk, .com, .org etc), the program does not continue onto the website.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you trying to validate, what is your issue and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be able to validate all website urls and prompt the user to enter a website url in the correct format.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
   ValidatewebsiteAddress(Me.TextBox1.Text)
End Sub


 Private Sub ValidatewebsiteAddress(ByVal _websiteAddress As String)
        If Not Regex.IsMatch(_websiteAddress, _
       "^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please complete url")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Thanks a lot")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you can, use something already available in .NET

```
Dim address As String = "StackOverflow"
Dim uri As System.Uri
If System.Uri.TryCreate(address, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, uri) Then
    ' if you get here, it's a real url
Else
    ' if you get here, it's not
End If
```